# How to find the attributes of a class in a database using the ID in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get PHP to echo all the attributes of a object in my database(ex. FirstName, LastName, age, DateOfBirth etc.) using only the ID that the user(mainly me) types in.

Like if I type in the ID: 2, it will echo all the attributes of the object with the ID of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to pull a row from a database. Well assuming you have the database setup, you should be able to use something like this:

```
    $con = new mysqli('yourhost','root','yourpassword','yourdb');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM `merica` WHERE user=?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $_GET['user']);
$statement->bind_result($FirstName, $LastName);
$statement->execute();
while ($statement->fetch()){
    echo $FirstName . "<br>";
            echo $LastName;
}
```

Then in a crude attempt to test that, you could type in your web browser's URL: `http://<yourserversip>/<scriptname>?user=2`

Comment: What I want is to type in the ID and have php "pull the row" with the ID i put in.